# Material DatePicker Range get range date selected

Tags: java, android, datepicker, material-components-android

i would like to use the material date picker to select a range of dates. 
How do I get the value of the selected range?

```
    long today = MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds();

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(today);

    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
    long january = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MARCH);
    long march = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
    long december = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    //CalendarConstraints
    CalendarConstraints.Builder constraintBuilder = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
    constraintBuilder.setValidator(new DateValidatorWeekdays());

    //MaterialDatePicker
    MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker();
    builder.setTitleText("Seleziona Date");
    //builder.setSelection(today);
    builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintBuilder.build());
    final MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker = builder.build();
```

I just tried materialDatePicker.getHeaderText () but if I would like to know the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I made like this:

Pair prendiRange = (Pair) materialDatePicker.getSelection();

```
            final Pair<Date, Date> rangeDate = new Pair<>(new Date(prendiRange.first), new Date(prendiRange.second));

            Date dataInizioRange = rangeDate.first;
            Date dataFineRange = rangeDate.second;
```